# AWS: Publish Git Commit/Tag Info During ElasticBeanstalk Deploy

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I would like to be able to publish the git `tag/commit` info to a versions page on my website.

It could simply be a static page with the version info.

Is there any way that I can script `eb deploy` to do something like this?

I just need to script `git describe --tags > public/version.txt` before deploying the files.

Any ideas?

I'm open to scripting it on the git side too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your git server you can simply do it inside a git hook.

> ### ***`post-receive`***
>
> The post-receive hook runs after the entire process is completed and can be used to update other services or notify users

---

#### Sample code:

> ***`post-receive hook`***

```
#!/bin/sh

# get the latest tag
tag = $(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)

# Output colors
red='\033[0;31m';
green='\033[0;32m';
yellow='\033[0;33m';
default='\033[0;m';

# personal touch :-)
echo "${red}"
echo "                                         "
echo "                   |ZZzzz                "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "                   |                     "
echo "      |ZZzzz      /^\            |ZZzzz  "
echo "      |          |~~~|           |       "
echo "      |        |-     -|        / \      "
echo "     /^\       |[]+    |       |^^^|     "
echo "  |^^^^^^^|    |    +[]|       |   |     "
echo "  |    +[]|/\/\/\/\^/\/\/\/\/|^^^^^^^|   "
echo "  |+[]+   |~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|    +[]|   "
echo "  |       |  []   /^\   []   |+[]+   |   "
echo "  |   +[]+|  []  || ||  []   |   +[]+|   "
echo "  |[]+    |      || ||       |[]+    |   "
echo "  |_______|------------------|_______|   "
echo "                                         "
echo "                                         "
echo "  ${green} Latest tag is: ${red} $tag    " 
echo "                                         "
echo "${default}"

exit 0;
```